# Use Vanilla JS variables inside blade component

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am trying to create a search bar. With every input change, a `fetch API` is triggered, which calls function in my Controller:

app.js

```
document.querySelector('#search')
        .addEventListener('input', event => {
            if(!event.target.value) return;
            fetch('/search' + '/' + event.target.value);
});
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use MeiliSearch\Client;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client('http://127.0.0.1:7700');
    }

    public function search($searchFor)
    {
        $indexes = $this->client->getAllIndexes();
        $searchResult = ['test' => 'test'];
        foreach($indexes as $index) {
            $searchResult[$index->getUid()] = $index->search($searchFor)->getHits();
        }
        
        return response($searchResult);
    }
}
```

Next, the Controller returns records for the given parameters and I want to catch them in JS and send them into blade component. Returning `view()` with results data in it is not an option since `view` won't rerender itself every time and that's why I am trying to do this through JS.

The reason I need that data inside blade is because I want to loop through it and display results under the search bar

Answer (score 0):

Return json_encoded value from your controller and get the result in fetch callback function then access any element from within the page and render the data.

*I am assuming the app.js file is included in your blade file.

Comment: I am returning an array of objects from controller and I want to loop over it with `@foreach`

Comment: in your case you need to render a partial view and pass it the data variable  like this         $html = View::make('countries.list', compact('countries'))->render();                                                    or else you can use foreach of js to re render the data.